# VBA to copy a row to new spreadsheet when column L value matches Column P

Tags: vba, excel

I run a weekly sales report and move some of the information based on the sales person name so I can then generate several reports.

I have code to sort the sales persons names in column "L", remove duplicate names and generate a new Column, "P". It then creates new sheets and names them after the names in "P". This way if I have sales people come and go I do not have to manually modify anything.

I currently filter the names and manually move the row data to their respective sheets. What I need is:

1- find all names in column L that match to the "Master name Column" Cell P2 or P3 or P4 etc.

2- copy all rows that have the name in column L to the worksheet of the same name. The worksheets names are the same as the names in Column P.

3- move the the next name in column P, cell P3, and start the match process again. . .`

I have attached the code I am using to create the worksheets from the names in column P.

```
Dim newSheet As Worksheet, regionSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Object
    Dim regionRange As String

    Set regionSheet = Sheets("EXPORT_QUERY")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    regionRange = "P2:" & regionSheet.Range("P2").End(xlDown).Address

    For Each cell In regionSheet.Range(regionRange)
       If SheetExists(cell.Value) = False Then
          Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
          Set newSheet = ActiveSheet
          newSheet.Name = cell.Value
          Application.DisplayAlerts = False
          Application.DisplayAlerts = True
       End If
    Next cell

   MsgBox "All worksheets have been created successfully"

   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the below code should wok well, if not there might be a few variables that will need some editing. do let me know if it errors out somewhere and i can help you with that bit. The assumption here is that Column P contains unique names only.

```
Set regionSheet = Sheets("EXPORT_QUERY")
regionRange = "P2:" & regionSheet.Range("P2").End(xlDown).Address


For Each cell In regionSheet.Range(regionRange)
    Range("A1:L" & Range("A" & rows.count).end(xlup).row).select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$L$" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=cell.Value
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$L$" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy

    Sheets(cell.Value).Select
    Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("EXPORT_QUERY").select
    Selection.AutoFilter
Next cell

MsgBox DONE"
```

Comment: Spectacular izzymo, i had to change Range("A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count line to ActiveSheet.Range or else it was trying to pull the data from the empy sheet. but this is exactly what i was looking for. Now to join the 2 codes into one control button and this step is done. Cheers again. Time for me to go home and have a beer

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do, in outline form, is what you have, then after you've created the sheet & before you move down to the next P2, P3, etc cell, create a loop that goes down your Column L from top to bottom, and if the name in L matches the name in Cell, then take that row and copy it to the newly created worksheet.

To do that, you'll need to have a RowCounter variable that starts out at whatever the first row you want to fill in the new worksheets is, and is incremented every time you copy a row from your "master" sheet to the newly created one.  This is your "destination" placeholder.  It is NOT the same as the loop that's going down column L, since they're counting different things.

It looks like what you have here is a good start; putting the new code in between the two Application.DisplayAlerts statements should work.

Hope that helps; it should at least get you headed in the right direction.